# How to use Perf4J with Profiled annotation in Gradle project?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, aspectj, perf4j

I have a Java Gradle project for which I am trying to use `Perf4J`. I found some examples of Perf4J only Maven. So, I modified one and ran it. Here is the Java class and Maven build file that works.

```
package com.mycompany.testapplication;

import org.apache.log4j.Appender;
import org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout;
import org.perf4j.aop.Profiled;

/**
 *
 * @author Ankit Gupta
 */
public class TestClass {

    final static Logger myLogger = Logger.getLogger("org.perf4j.TimingLogger");
    final static Appender myAppender;

    static {
        myLogger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
        // Define Appender     
        myAppender = new ConsoleAppender(new SimpleLayout());

        //myAppender.setLayout(new SimpleLayout());  
        myLogger.addAppender(myAppender);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestClass test = new TestClass();
        test.run();
    }

    @Profiled(
            tag = "sampleTag"
    )
    private void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TestClass.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

and the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestApplication</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>


    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <weaveDependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.perf4j</groupId>
                            <artifactId>perf4j</artifactId>
                        </dependency>
                    </weaveDependencies>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <!-- use this goal to weave all your main classes -->
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                            <!-- use this goal to weave all your test classes -->
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.perf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>perf4j</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.13</version>
            <classifier>log4jonly</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-jexl</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-jexl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


</project>
```

The code above works fine and gives me the expected output. Now, I want to do the same to my gradle project, but I don't know how. Since, I am using `@Profiled` annotation, I realized that I want `AspectJ`. I found this [plugin](https://github.com/eveoh/gradle-aspectj) and wrote a build.gradle file for the same Java class as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = '1.6'

if (!hasProperty('mainClass')) {
    ext.mainClass = 'com.mycompany.testapplication.TestClass'
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.eveoh.nl/content/repositories/releases"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "nl.eveoh:gradle-aspectj:1.4"
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies{
    compile 'org.perf4j:perf4j:0.9.16'
    compile 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.6.7'
    compile 'org.perf4j:perf4j:0.9.13:log4jonly'
    compile 'commons-jexl:commons-jexl:1.1'
    compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
}

project.ext {
    aspectjVersion = '1.6.7'
}

apply plugin: 'aspectj'
```

The `gradle build clean` and `gradle run` commands do not give any error or warning. However, I do not see the perf4j log on the console. How can I fix this so that I can use perf4j with Gradle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to specify the external code to weave in (the line with `ajInpath`). I adopted your script (included application plugin to execute with `gradle run`, updated version numbers and changed to Java 8:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://maven.eveoh.nl/content/repositories/releases" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "nl.eveoh:gradle-aspectj:1.4"
    }
}

project.ext {
    aspectjVersion = '1.8.1'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'aspectj'
apply plugin: 'application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.perf4j:perf4j:0.9.16:log4jonly'
    compile 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.1'
    compile 'commons-jexl:commons-jexl:1.1'
    compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'

    ajInpath 'org.perf4j:perf4j:0.9.16:log4jonly'
}

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
mainClassName = 'com.mycompany.testapplication.TestClass'
```

Tested with Gradle 2.0. It would be a good idea to put the version numbers into variables and to use the gradle wrapper.